# Is this integral operator involving Dirac delta diagonalizable?

Tags: functional-analysis, dirac-delta

For a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H} = L^2([0, 1])$ and a linear operator $L: \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$, then if $L$ is Hilbert-Schmidt (e.g. $\sum_{i} \lVert L e_i \rVert^2 < \infty$ for any orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$ for $\mathcal{H}$, where the norm is the one you expect for $\mathcal{H}$) and self-adjoint, then $L$ may be diagonalized and written in the form
\begin{equation}
L = \sum_i \lambda_i \phi_i \otimes \phi_i^* \tag{1}
\end{equation}
with respect to eigenvalues $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and eigenfunctions $\phi_i \in \mathcal{H}$, and $L$ is trace-class if the sequence of eigenvalues converges. I am used to integral operators of the form $(Lf)(x) = \int dy k(x, y) f(y)$ for positive definite $k$ and $f \in \mathcal{H}$, in which case the above conditions hold for writing this operator in the form of Eq. $(1)$.

I would like to know if it is possible to diagonalize the following operator $L_\delta$ involving the delta function:

$$
(L_\delta f)(x) = \int dy q(x) \delta (y-x) f(y) = f(x)q(x), \tag{2}
$$
where $q \geq 0$ and $\lVert q \rVert_1 = 1$ (i.e. $q$ is a probability distribution with respect to its argument.

I think this is not possible because $L_\delta$ doesn't seem to be Hilbert-Schmidt in the first place (but I couldn't prove that explictly).

Comment: The integral used to define $L_\delta$ is not actually well defined, you cant integrate dirac delta against an $L^2$ function  (whose value at a point is ill defined). That being said, the right hand side of your definition actually works (simply setting $L_\delta f (x) = f(x)q(x)$). You can also see from this, that the operator is not Hilbert-Schmidt, because the kernel $k$ would have to satisfy $\int k(x,y) f(y) dy =f(x) q(x) $, which is clearly not possible (if $f,q$ are $C^\infty$ this would mean that $k(x,y) = \delta(x-y) q(x)$, but that is not even a function).

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence, I thought a delta $\delta(x)$ was _defined_ as the functional that evaluates $f(0)$, usually written in terms of an integral? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: But $f(0)$ doest not make sense for a function in $L^2$ ;) While multiplying two a.e. defined functions in dual $L^p$ spaces makes sense a.e.

Comment: Your operator is a nice multiplication operator. It is continuous iff $q\in L^\infty$. If $q\equiv 1$ it equals the identity, which is not Hilbert-Schmidt etc.